# Set Google style bottomsheet Dialog in Android Studio App?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

This is my code that gives a BottomSheet Dialog. After implementation it gives me a normal BottomSheet Dialog, how can i make this Bottom Sheet look like Google BottomSheet Dialog with rounded corners and something like a middle gray line at the top?

Even if it doesn't look exactly like the Bottomsheet Facebook and Google uses, I just want to have a rounded corner for this code.

What do I change or add in my code?

`MainActivity.Java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDialog();
            }
        });
}

private void openDialog() {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sheet_main, null);
        dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(view);
        TextView camera_sel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.camera);
        TextView gallery_sel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        camera_sel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePhotoFromCamera();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        gallery_sel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePhotoFromGallery();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
}
```

`sheet_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_camera"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Camera"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_panorama"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE:

I was able to achieve this by adding these to my style.xml and setting it on the theme used for my dialog activity. Thanks!

```
<style name="HomeTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Demo.BottomSheetDialog</item>
 </style>

 <style
     name="ThemeOverlay.Demo.BottomSheetDialog"
     parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
     <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/Widget.Demo.BottomSheet</item>
 </style>

 <style name="Widget.Demo.BottomSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet">
     <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Demo</item>
 </style>

 <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Demo" parent="">
     <item name="cornerSize">18dp</item>
     <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
 </style>
```